# Crontab function scheduler in seconds timer

Tags: postgresql, timer, cron, scheduler, time-frequency

How to set any postgres function in crontab with frequency of seconds?
Thank you in advance.

Tried searching for seconds timer scheduling. But looks like postgres / crontab doesn't support for seconds setup. only minute, hour, day, etc options are available. Looking for any alternative option.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your PostgreSQL version is 10+ then you can use [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) extension to schedule scripts directly from the database.

As stated in the documentation,

> ... You can also use '[1-59] seconds' to schedule a job based on an interval.